# como usar contadores en una lista de diccionarios python

Tags: python, python-3.x

n una empresa de la ciudad que ofrece paquetes de televisión internacional, se requiere conocer el total de ingresos y el promedio de ingresos por cada uno de sus dos tipos de televisión Streaming que tienen: 1. Amazon Prime y 2. Netflix. Se deben procesar N cantidad de facturas con la siguiente información:
• Abonado (A que tipo de paquete pertenece).
• Valor a pagar.
Obtener el total de ingresos y el promedio de ingresos redondeado a un dígito por cada paquete de televisión internacional que los clientes han contratado con la empresa de paquetes internacionales.
Escriba una función que reciba como parámetros: una lista de diccionarios que contenga la siguiente información:
• abonado: “amazon_prime” o “netflix”
• valor_a_pagar: int
Retorne un diccionario con la siguiente estructura:
• {total: int, promedio_amazonprime: float, promedio_netflix: float}

Ya tengo el return pero no logro hacer funcionar los contadores, agradezco mucho si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
def calcular_ingresos(datos:list) -> dict:

    amazon = 0
    net = 0
    
    total_amazon = 0
    total_netflix = 0
    total_ingreso = total_amazon + total_netflix
    
    promedio_amazon = total_amazon / 4
    promedio_netflix = total_netflix / 3

    for item in datos:
        if item["abonado"] == "amazon_prime":
            total_amazon += item["valor_a_pagar"]
            amazon += 1
        elif item["abonado"] == "netflix":
            total_netflix += item["valor_a_pagar"]
            net += 1

    resultado = {
        "total": total_ingreso,
        "promedio_amazonprime": float(promedio_amazon),
        "promedio_netflix": float(promedio_netflix),
        }

    return resultado


clientes = [
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 30000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 22000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 28000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 35000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "amazon_prime",
    "valor_a_pagar": 23000
    },
    {
    "abonado": "netflix",
    "valor_a_pagar": 18000
    }
]


print(calcular_ingresos(clientes))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo una operación con las variables (que tienen el valor de 0) mas no cambias ni vuelves a operar con ellas, y solo lo retornas en tu diccionario, por lo que te devolverá `0` en todo, solución numero 1, mover 3 líneas de código a bajo del ciclo `for`

```py
...
    for item in datos:
        if item["abonado"] == "amazon_prime":
            total_amazon += item["valor_a_pagar"]
            amazon += 1
        elif item["abonado"] == "netflix":
            total_netflix += item["valor_a_pagar"]
            net += 1

    total_ingreso = total_amazon + total_netflix
    
    promedio_amazon = total_amazon / 4
    promedio_netflix = total_netflix / 3
    ...
```

Solución 2, mejorar la función y hacerla mas *dinámica* , para esto utilizaremos 2 compresion de lista para tener los valores de cada compañía

```py
def calcular_ingresos(datos:list) -> dict:   

    #guardamos el valor solo cuando abonado es netflix
    netflix = [dato["valor_a_pagar"] for dato in datos if dato["abonado"] == "netflix"] 
    #guardamos el valor solo cuando abonado es amazon_prime
    amazon = [dato["valor_a_pagar"] for dato in datos if dato["abonado"] == "amazon_prime"]

    #para sacar el promedio primeros sacamos la suma y 
    #luego dividimos entre el total de datos
    resultado = {
        "total": sum(netflix+amazon), #sumamos ambos resultado
        "promedio_amazonprime": round(sum(amazon)/len(amazon),3), #utilizamos round() para redondear
        "promedio_netflix": round(sum(netflix)/len(netflix),3),
        }

    return resultado # retornamos
```

Para redondear el resultado, se utilizó la función `round()` la cual recibe como primer parámetro el numero a redondear y como segundo, el  número de decimales al que va a redondear, algo así `round(num,decimal)`

**resultado**

```
{
  'total': 191000, 
  'promedio_amazonprime': 25750.0, 
  'promedio_netflix': 29333.333
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambas opciones trabajan muy bien (sobre todo la segunda), Perfectamente solucionado